# Filtering `catch` tests by label when running with `ctest`

Tags: cmake

I am currently using [`ctest`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/ctest.html) to run tests written with the [Catch framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch). I would like to be able to filter which tests I run based on the internal Catch tags; for instance, I would like to be easily prevent any tests tagged `[FUTURE]` from running.

For a single test executable, ignoring `ctest`, this is straightforward:

```
myTestName '~[FUTURE]'
```

But I don't see any way to pass the `'~[FUTURE]'` argument to the Catch tests via `ctest`. This [should be possible](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-March/028058.html) `--test-command`, but (1) `--test-command` doesn't seem to do anything without `--build-and-test` (which is not what I want) and (2) this apparently only works for one test at a time anyway, which is also not what I want (I just want to run `ctest` on my entire project).

I could just use `ctest -N` to get the names of the tests to run, then run the tests myself, but I don't know of any way to get the test filepath from `ctest` so I'd have to run `find` on all the test-names, and at that point I'm basically implementing my own test runner.

**P.S.** There are no existing tags for `ctest` or the Catch test framework, and I don't have the rep to create them. I'm not really sure what other tags would apply here. I'm only using the `cmake` tag because `ctest` is part of `cmake`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jorgeh No, I did not. It does seem like a pretty glaring omission in `ctest`....

Comment: I need something a little like this, so here's my current vague idea: you could declare each test to ctest twice, once with `~[FUTURE]` as my-test-name and once without as my-test-name-future. Then you could filter them with a ctest regex. Alternatively you could add a ctest label to the future ones and use ctest's label filtering to run the right ones (might be a bit more robust than regexing the name).

You could use a cmake wrapper function for test registration to make sure it was done consistently.